How to create a new dataframe column that stores the second valid value of another value column in a rolling 24hr period
I have the following dataframe:

It has a group column, a timestamp column and a value column (rr).
i want to create a new column (denoted by rr_second_last_in_past_24h) that stores the second last valid value in the past 24hrs, within each group.  So the rolling 24hr period restarts for each new group.  The dataframe is already sorted by group and event_timestamp.
So far I have tried this using a rolling function with rows, like this:
df_max = df.groupby('ENCNTR_ID')[f].rolling('24h', min_periods=1).agg(lambda rows: rows[-2])
But this returns the actual value in the second last row, rather than the last valid (non null/nan) value.

Just apply dropna to rows value like this agg(lambda rows: rows.dropna().iloc[-2])
